# NSString always returning nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

Can someone help me figure out what I might be missing?

I'm getting this error, and seems like something ULTRA simple, but I have no idea where it comes from! There are a couple of posts about it. But none seem to relate. All I'm doing is,

Setting a property,

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString * rate;
```

and in my viewDidLoad,

```
self.rate = @"bananas";
NSLog(@"self.rate %@",self.rate);
```

I keep getting in the console -> self.rate (null)

Any help is most appreciated
Thank you!!

Nuno

p.s. I also tried to set a string pointer and also tried to alloc]init] (but I don't really see any for reason for that to be the problem, and it wasn't)... no success so far.

Also, property is @synthesized

Comment: Why is it `weak`? Have you tried setting it `strong` instead?

Comment: Maybe self has become nil? just a thought :-S

Comment: Just to check: Have you created setters/getters for it using the synthesize command?

Comment: @epatel: How would that work?

Comment: Yes, getters and setters were created with @synthesize.

Comment: I think Guven is making sure that you don't happen to have a method called `setRate`, because when you do `self.rate = @"bananas"`, that's the method that is called.

Comment: Ho I didn't understand! But no, I didn't type them manually. I only used the @synthesize

Comment: @W'rkncacnter Well, self could have been set somewhere earlier in `viewDidLoad`? and then any method sent to nil wouldn't do anything

Comment: @epatel: The code inside `viewDidLoad` couldn't run if `self` was `nil`, thus there would be no output _at all_, rather than `self.rate (null)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @Guven said, I was really **setting a setter at the same time as I was using a @synthesize** when I shouldn't.

I didn't realize I had an "old" method setRate laying around in the code.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Nice! It is always time-consuming to track down errors like this.

Answer (score 1):

Make your property a strong property

Comment: Or even better, make it `copy`.

Comment: Just tried that. self.rate = [@"bananas" copy]; No success :/

Comment: Also (copy, nonatomic), no success also.

Answer (score 1):

**possible solutions:**

1.(as long as nothing else has a strong pointer to it)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * rate ;        //or use (copy, nonatomic), depends..
```

*2.you forgot to

```
@synthesize rate = _rate;
```

3.self is nil

*edit:*

4.setter/getter buggy

*correction for 2., As Rob pointed out in comment below:

> "The @synthesize is optional, as of Xcode 4.4. And in earlier versions, it would be a compile error"

Comment: The `@synthesize` is optional, as of Xcode 4.4. And in earlier versions, it would be a compile error.

Comment: I just tried that to, (copy, nonatomic). No success. This is VERY strange :\ I can access several properties. But not this one. self is my current ViewController in this case.